# How do I get ngrams for all combinations of words in a sentence?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, tfidf, ngrams

Lets say I have a sentence "I need multiple ngrams". If I create bigrams using Tf idf vectorizer it will create bigrams only using consecutive words. i.e. I will get "I need", "need multiple", "multiple ngrams".

How can I get "I mutiple", "I ngrams", "need ngrams"?

Comment: ngrams by definition are continuous. "I need", "need multiple", "multiple ngrams" aren'r ngrams. You could write a simple logic for this yourself.

Comment: I posted an answer to get your desired output. But I agree with Palak. These aren't real ngrams, and it begs the question, _why do you really need this?_

Comment: I am creating a training dataset for a binary classifier where I am trying to create features using combination of words. Tf idf vectorizer creates vectors for ngrams using conecutive words. I was thinking if it is possible to create vectors for combination of non consecutive words using tf idf vectorizer?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

For example:

```
s = "I need multiple ngrams"
s_list = s.split(" ") # Assumes you tokenize with white space.

import itertools

combinations = list(itertools.combinations(s_list, 2)) # the second argument ("2" in this case) is the size of the n-gram.
```

You will get the following output:

```
[('I', 'need'), ('I', 'multiple'), ('I', 'ngrams'), ('need', 'multiple'), ('need', 'ngrams'), ('multiple', 'ngrams')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code as well:

```
s = "I need multiple ngrams"
tokens = s.split(' ')

res = [(tokens[i],tokens[j]) for i in range(len(tokens) -1) for j in range(i+1, len(tokens))]
```

Output:

```
[('I', 'need'), ('I', 'multiple'), ('I', 'ngrams'), ('need', 'multiple'), ('need', 'ngrams'), ('multiple', 'ngrams')]
```